# Hiding div using a button

Tags: javascript, php, css

I am using the follwoing to hide a layer once the yes button is clicked how ever only the yes button goes (the no button remains) and I still can't select products behind
the 'woverlay' div

```
<?php
if($verification == 1){
?>
<div id="woverlay" style="display:none;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;width:100%;height:100%;opacity:1.0;filter:alpha(opacity=100);-moz-opacity:.8; z-index:10000;text-align:center;"> 

        <div style="position:absolute;top:25%;left:20%;width:60%;padding:20px;">
        <div id="content">
        <div class="top">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center">
      <h1><?php echo $text_verify_title; ?></h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="middle">
        <table bgcolor="white"><tr><td> 
            <?php echo $text_verify_text; ?><br /><br />
            <a class="button" onclick="hide()"><span><?php echo $text_yes; ?></span></a> 
            <a href="index.php" class="button"><span><?php echo $text_no; ?></span></a> 
            <br /><br /> 
</td></tr></table> 
 </div>
  <div class="bottom">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="center"></div>
  </div>
</div>
        </div> 
    </div> 
   <script src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        if($.cookie("valide")==null){

        var w = document.getElementById('woverlay');
        w.style.display = 'block';
        document.body.style.height = '100%';
        document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        }
        function hide(){
        var h = document.getElementById('woverlay');
        h.style.display = 'none';
        $.cookie("valide", 'true')
        }
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Thx Steve

Comment: why you mix, jquery with standar js?

Comment: That's how the code came - it's an Opencart addon

Comment: the code is correct, you must debug with firefox/firebug console or put the code in http://jsfiddle.net/ to check it